# Fast quicksort implementation

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, quick-sort

Just for learning purposes i wrote an implementation of quicksort algorithm.

I made some modifications to the algorithm to make it faster, that are:

- two pivots setted to the boundaries of the middle partition(<, **=**, >), to avoid having two other variables counting the equal elements
- the partitioning method checks first the presence of less(in left partition) or greater(in right partition) than pivot elements, if both are present, rather than moving the pivot twice, it just swaps them; if not behaves normally.

I benchmarked it a bit and compared the performance to std::sort; my algorithm, with random elements is faster than the STD one when there are more than 10000000, otherwise, with less elements std::sort is faster by some milliseconds(see below for actual benchmark results)

```
#include <algorithm>

template<class iterator>
void quickSort(iterator begin, iterator end)
{
    if (end - begin > 1)
    {
        auto lpivot = begin + (end - begin) / 2;
        auto rpivot = lpivot;

        auto pValue = *lpivot;

        auto left_it = lpivot - 1;
        auto right_it = rpivot + 1;

        auto lValue = *left_it;
        auto rValue = *right_it;

        bool isGreater = false;
        bool isLess = false;

        while (left_it != begin-1 || right_it != end)
        {
            if (lValue >= pValue)
            {
                if (lValue == pValue)
                {
                    lpivot--;
                    std::iter_swap(lpivot, left_it);
                }
                else
                    isGreater = true;
            }

            if (rValue <= pValue)
            {
                if (rValue == pValue)
                {
                    rpivot++;
                    std::iter_swap(rpivot, right_it);
                }
                else
                    isLess = true;
            }
            if (isGreater && isLess)
            {
                std::iter_swap(left_it, right_it);
            }
            else if (isGreater)
            {
                if (left_it != lpivot - 1)
                    std::iter_swap(left_it, lpivot - 1);
                std::iter_swap(rpivot - 1, lpivot - 1);
                std::iter_swap(rpivot, rpivot - 1);
                lpivot--;
                rpivot--;
            }
            else if (isLess)
            {
                if (right_it != rpivot + 1)
                    std::iter_swap(right_it, rpivot + 1);
                std::iter_swap(lpivot + 1, rpivot + 1);
                std::iter_swap(lpivot, lpivot + 1);
                lpivot++;
                rpivot++;
            }

            if (left_it != begin - 1)
                left_it--;
            if (right_it != end)
                right_it++;

            lValue = *left_it;
            rValue = *right_it;

            isGreater = false;
            isLess = false;
        }

        quickSort(begin, lpivot);
        quickSort(rpivot + 1, end);
    }
}
```

**My algorithm benchmark**

```
1000000  random integers --------> 80 ms
2000000  random integers --------> 165 ms
3000000  random integers --------> 247 ms
10000000 random integers --------> 780 ms

1000000  binary random integers -> 4 ms
2000000  binary random integers -> 9 ms
3000000  binary random integers -> 14 ms
10000000 binary random integers -> 49 ms

1000000  sorted integers --------> 19 ms
2000000  sorted integers --------> 43 ms
3000000  sorted integers --------> 65 ms
10000000 sorted integers --------> 232 ms

1000000  reversed integers ------> 17 ms
2000000  reversed integers ------> 37 ms
3000000  reversed integers ------> 60 ms
10000000 reversed integers ------> 216 ms
```

**std::sort benchmark**

```
1000000  random integers --------> 71 ms
2000000  random integers --------> 160 ms
3000000  random integers --------> 237 ms
10000000 random integers --------> 800 ms

1000000  binary random integers -> 4 ms
2000000  binary random integers -> 9 ms
3000000  binary random integers -> 13 ms
10000000 binary random integers -> 45 ms

1000000  sorted integers --------> 9 ms
2000000  sorted integers --------> 21 ms
3000000  sorted integers --------> 33 ms
10000000 sorted integers --------> 137 ms

1000000  reversed integers ------> 12 ms
2000000  reversed integers ------> 25 ms
3000000  reversed integers ------> 40 ms
10000000 reversed integers ------> 150 ms
```

**bechmark code**

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 1000000);
    //std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 1); //just 0s and 1s array

    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(values), 10000000, std::bind(dist, gen)); //random

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        //values.push_back(i);              //sorted array
        //values.push_back(10000000 - i);   //reversed array
    }

    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Time;
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds ms;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<float> fsec;
    auto t0 = Time::now();

    //quickSort(values.begin(), values.end());
    //std::sort(values.begin(), values.end());

    auto t1 = Time::now();
    fsec fs = t1 - t0;
    ms d = std::chrono::duration_cast<ms>(fs);
    std::cout << fs.count() << "s\n";
    std::cout << d.count() << "ms\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried benchmarking the same code with clang 3.8 un Ubuntu x64, and I got the same result as seen in the comments, so it is just visual studio with a slow std sort implementation

(I know those arrows suck, they are there just for clarity)

Comment: It might help if you provide the benchmark code too (the absolute numbers won't be comparable anywhere else, but improvements relative to the baseline might be applicable).

Comment: Timing is hard. Running it only once is bad idea. Run the sort 10,000 times in main() and average the numbers after. Then run the application 3 times to make sure the numbers are similar.

Comment: I ran your benchmark in random distribution mode with 10,000,000 elements and got: `yours = 985 ms, std::sort = 674 ms`.  Smaller and larger numbers of elements were about the same ratio.  Not sure why my numbers are so different than yours.

Comment: @JS1, may be you got "unlucky" with the input? :)

Comment: @Incomputable The input is random and I ran it several times, so I don't think so.  It's probably some difference in the compiler, OS, or CPU.  I'm hoping other people will report their numbers so we can tell whose numbers are more realistic.

Comment: @JS1, I'll run it in a few minutes. I was just kidding about that comment, even the worst numbers couldn't make that much difference.

Comment: @JS1, could you please share the benchmarking code? I didn't write up my own, though we'll probably have some differences if not measured with the same code. With the OP's code I have 847ms for OP and 839 for std::sort. I'd say in range of error.

Comment: @JS1, then it seems like it's pretty scattered between us three. I'll try to put together more heavy benchmark. May be with graph plots, if I'll manage to get the darn parser to work.

Comment: @Incomputable I used the OP's code.  I just ran it again on a different machine and OS, and I got 1085 ms for OP and 990 ms for std::sort.  Original numbers were on Cygwin g++ 32-bit.  These latest numbers are for Linux g++ 64-bit.  I find that the gap narrows if you narrow the uniform distribution (so that there are more identical numbers).

Comment: @JS1 , thats close to my ubuntu 16.04 clang-5.0.

Comment: I am using visual studio, but I'm not sure if that's important

Comment: @DanDan It may be that visual studio has a completely different (and slower) `std::sort` than gcc or clang, which is causing the discrepancy.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 v141 with optimizations set to -O2

Comment: I'll try with clang and check that discrepancy

Comment: My numbers are 900ms for your algorithm and ~700ms for `std::sort`. clang++-5.0 with libc++.

Comment: Maybe it helps to incorporate these optimizations https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devdev/2006/01/18/efficient-selection-and-partial-sorting-based-on-quicksort/

Comment: Avoid statements like `auto pValue = *lpivot;`! This copies(!) the dereferenced value. Imagine you are sorting big `std::string`s. You don't know how costly that could be! Use `auto&& pValue = *lpivot;` is most general.

Comment: Oh, Nevermind. I just realised, that you reassign that variable!

Comment: @Maikel, I don't see it being reassigned. I included that in my review, so I hope I'm right.

Comment: @JS1, sorry for being off for so long. I've finally benchmarked the stuff. And yes, it seems like some standard library implementations of `std::sort` are just slow. There is some more information in my answer.

Comment: @Maikel, what version of libc++ do you have? On my trunk version it seems to be slower. Its roughly from the time you posted an answer to my transform iterator

Comment: @DanDan, I accidentally got the benchmarking code comitted into my repository which is under unlicense license. I will replace it with some other code in the future, but I would like to ask if it is okay for me to keep it in the commit history? It's just a pain for me to deal with git.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that the images in the post are under [license of MatPlotLib](http://matplotlib.org/users/license.html), since I've used the modules to draw the plots.

I've finally run the benchmarks. Although they were pretty synthetic, I believe I nuked things that could affect the benchmark to the best of my abilities.

System setup: intel core i7 2600, 8GB ram 1333MHz, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with latest updates, clang++-5.0-trunk, no performance flags except the ones passed with cmake's release mode, libc++-trunk (I believe latest version).

[image]

The image above is for elements in range [0; 100], generator: `std::random_device` (hardware, since intel cpu and libc++)

The following one is for elements in range [0; 100'000], `std::mt19937_64`, default constructed.

[image]

Do note that comparing two images doesn't make much sense due to varying setup and input range. Though the relation between speed and input range is pretty clear, especially for `std::sort`.  The reason might be in more swaps that are to be made.

As you can see, your algorithm has *algorithmic* performance gain compared to libc++'s `std::sort`. The spikes near the end is me watching youtube videos, since the benchmark run for around 1.5 hours, and greatly slowed down at the very end. I believe the reason for slow down is not the algorithms, but the `std::random_device` (the overhead from it is excluded from the benchmark itself), so if anyone would want to benchmark the code in the future, don't use `std::random_device` to generate big data sets!

I've read somewhere on their bug tracker that their `std::sort` use some sophisticated quick sort. For further information I recommend having a look at this [bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20837).

**Code Review:**

I'm not great at algorithms, so I'll mention code style and some improvements for generic code.

**Comments:**

Yeah, this is pretty niche. But hey, I can't remember what I've written a month ago, although I'm noted as the one who has pretty tough long time memory among my peers. You could at least keep a markdown or tex/latex file around with it that explains . It is impossible to oversell code clarity.

**iterator categories:**

With C++17, I (believe) there are 7 categories. `std::list` will probably have bidirectional category, and [it is probably good to fallback to merge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222730/why-is-merge-sort-preferred-over-quick-sort-for-sorting-linked-lists). I haven't checked that myself, but my professor agrees with the post.

As a result, you could explicitly specify that you would "like" random access iterators, by changing declaration:

```
template<class RandomAccessIt>
void quickSort(RandomAccessIt begin, RandomAccessIt end)
```

it will probably fix the conformance bugs coming from the specialized version that you've probably built on the current code. From personal experience I know that it is quite hard to get full conformance to specification.

**Minor things:**

```
auto pValue = *lpivot;
```

That will probably increase type constraints. From what I've seen in the code, you don't modify it. So it should be:

```
const auto& pValue = *lpivot;
```

The key to understanding is that for any function of the following form:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T value);
```

`T` will have references stripped of it if it is rvalue. [Proof](https://ideone.com/52ygoc). So the code is practically copy constructing the `pValue`, which could be very expensive.

**Benchmarking approach:**

Although your benchmarking code is good to get *a very rough* measure of performance, I don't think it will suffise when you will start squeezing performance. Also, documenting your thoughts on every stage is going to be a very good approach. In short, all of the software engineering practices should be applied here, plus benchmarking:

- Always have a baseline. It is usually the fastest version of the code. If you are not measuring the code against something, you're not making it faster.
- Setup multiple situations. I don't think everyone wants to always sort `int`s. There might be compilation errors, *undefined behavior*, and whatnot.
- Raw runtime is not the best thing. If you'll read the bug report I've linked, a user will mention that raw runtime is not portable and heavily environment dependent. My voice probably won't mean anything, but I agree with him/her. Better measures are throughput, data reads/writes. I believe all of the things can be captured by using google benchmark library.

**Code used for benchmark:**

Modified version of my benchmark v2.

Code in the `main()`:

```
std::size_t counter = 0;
auto quicksort_bench = [&counter](std::vector<int>& v)
{
    quickSort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << v.front() << ' ' << counter++ << '\n'; //just to tell compiler to not optimize the code away
};

auto stdsort_bench = [&counter](std::vector<int>& v)
{
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << v.front() << ' ' << counter++ << '\n'; //ditto
};

auto checked_bench = shino::benchmarker(generator{}, quicksort_bench, stdsort_bench);

for (std::size_t i = 1000; i <= 1'000'000; i += 100)
{
    checked_bench.time(i, 3); //3 means runcount for the same dataset
}

checked_bench.save_as<std::chrono::microseconds>("./benchmarks/metafile.txt",
                      {"custom quicksort.txt", "standard sort.txt"});
```

Generator was slightly tricky to write to not cause slow down and not run out of memory:

```
class generator
{
    std::unique_ptr<shino::random_int_generator<>> gen;
public:
    using input_type = std::size_t;

    generator():
            gen(std::make_unique<shino::random_int_generator<>>(0, 100)) //replaced with 0, 100'000 on second run
    {}

    generator(generator&& other):
            gen(std::move(other.gen))
    {}

    std::tuple<std::vector<int>> operator()(input_type input)
    {
        static std::vector<int> v(input);
        if (v.size() != input)
        {
            v.resize(input);
            (*gen)(v.begin(), v.end());
        }

        return v;
    }
};
```

Generation of the input happens outside of "critical section", so it shouldn't affect the benchmark. Also, the default is `std::random_device`, which is the reason why benchmark run for so long.

and a python script to draw the plots, which is I think irrelevant, since it doesn't modify the data at all.

Comment: I removed the links to my posts to not look like self promotional, let me know if I should put them back. Or you can just roll back the edit.

Comment: Are you only generating numbers in the range 0..100?

Comment: @JS1, yes. I can add more if you want to, but I found it to be reasonable. I've changed the generator to `std::mt19937_64`, and I believe results will be available in a few minutes.

Comment: @JS1, update: it slowed down greatly. Thanks for noticing that. I'll get some sleep and post the results after the run will be finished.

Comment: @JS1, input range clearly affected the results, but not overall meaning of them: `std::sort` is still slower in those cases. I might investigate the relation later.

Comment: I am also not good at algorithms, but I am confused with the fact that the algorithms seem to be of *O(N)* complexity instead of *O(NlnN)*. Am I missing smth?

Comment: @LRDPRDX, well, IIRC, on average quick sort is linear. It is just that I'm not generating worst cases, and big O applies to worst cases. Uniformly random input is usually more about Theta, the O with dash in the middle. Also the data is very small. Usually stuff that fits in L3 cache of CPU is fast, and big O becomes less relevant due to various tricks that CPU can perform in those cases. Try to invoke the sort on bigger data and deliberately making life of the algorithm harder by generating bad partitions.

Comment: @Incomputable, No. On average quicksort is in the class *O(NlnN)*, in the worst cases (for example, if the list to be sorted is already sorted) it is in the class *O(N^2)*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 0):

I would think this minor change will improve performance on larger datasets

Original

```
if (lValue >= pValue) // == is redundant changeto <
   {
    if (lValue == pValue)
       {
        lpivot--;
        std::iter_swap(lpivot, left_it);
       }
    else
       isGreater = true;
   }

   if (rValue <= pValue) // == is redundant changeto >
      {
       if (rValue == pValue)
          {
           rpivot++;
           std::iter_swap(rpivot, right_it);
          }
       else
          isLess = true;
   }
```

Change to

```
if (!(lValue < pValue)) // leaving == and >
   {
    if (lValue == pValue)
       {
        lpivot--;
        std::iter_swap(lpivot, left_it);
       }
    else
       isGreater = true;
   }

if (!(rValue > pValue)) // leaving == and <
   {
    if (rValue == pValue)
       {
        rpivot++;
        std::iter_swap(rpivot, right_it);
       }
    else
       isLess = true;
   }
```

I am going to look at think about how to improve your performance on sequenced data.

Edit: changed !(...) to (!(...))

Comment: Your code is wrong, if a value is less or greater than another, it can't equal that

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya, I believe there is `std::is_sorted` (not sure though). That way you can know for sure.

Comment: @Incomputable I assume your referencing avoiding the pitfalls of sorting sorted data, that is certainly a valid check. The more I thought about it, the less I was inclined to pursue it as the OP request no design change.

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya, no, I just wanted to say that you will be able to support the claim of working code by a fact. So, merely for debugging purposes. I'll probably include your code into the benchmark as well, though it will be coming not earlier than tomorrow :)

Comment: @Incomputable Do you have reason to believe the code changes I suggested are flawed? If so please give me an "opportunity for improvement" (ofi's are what make the world go round)

Comment: @EnigmaMaitreya, I didn't really check the code yet. I just saw that OP was saying that some parts of the code are broken, so I thought that you need some strength in the discussion by stating the fact that it works, not claiming it :)